# What java do to interpret unix timestamps?

Tags: java, python, mongodb

I observed a behavior in java that I think a little bit different. If someone can shed light on my question I would be appreciated.

I have a project which uses MongoDB, Spring Data MongoDB at the backend. This is an android project.

When I insert a date field into a document in mongoDB, it is interpretted as ISODate in mongoDB. This gets converted by spring for me to `java.util.Date`. I have tried to convert this what I called to be a unix timestamp in this [website](http://www.unixtimestamp.com/), and it output some date in year 49311. I gave the timestamp as `1493967548032`

In addition to that, when I tried to convert this timestamp to natural human readable format in python3.5, I get OSError which saying "Invalid argument".

```
timestamp = 1493967548032
datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(timestamp)
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
OSError                                   Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-35-a8b8548bb1ff> in <module>()
----> 1 datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(timestamp)

OSError: [Errno 22] Invalid argument
```

However, java.util.Date data types have no problem with understanding the same thing with each other. And they interpret this timestamp as "2017-May-05". I need to understand how to interpret these java-style timestamps in python in order to test features in future.

I am on a Windows 10 x64 machine.

Comment: When you say "test features in the future", do you mean 47294 years into the future?

Comment: By the way, the java.util.Date class is now legacy, supplanted by java.time.Instant.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Java's `Date` takes its parameter in [milliseconds](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Date.html#Date(long)):

> ```
> public Date(long date)
> ```
>
> Allocates a Date object and initializes it to represent the specified number of **milliseconds** since the standard base time known as "the epoch", namely January 1, 1970, 00:00:00 GMT.

Python's `datetime.fromtimestamp` takes its parameter in [seconds](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#datetime-objects).

> ```
> classmethod datetime.fromtimestamp(timestamp[, tz])
> ```
>
> Return the local date and time corresponding to the **POSIX timestamp**

(POSIX timestamps are in seconds)

So, simply divide your milliseconds by 1000:

```
>>> datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(1493967548032 / 1000)
datetime.datetime(2017, 5, 5, 7, 59, 8)
```

If you want to keep the milliseconds, make sure you use float arithmetic:

```
>>> datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp((float) 1493967548032 / 1000)
datetime.datetime(2017, 5, 5, 7, 59, 8, 32000)
```

Answer (score 1):

divide this value **1493967548032** by thousand before converting to date, because the parameter's unit is seconds, not milliseconds.

That will produce:

```
>>> datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(1493967548.032)
datetime.datetime(2017, 5, 5, 7, 59, 8, 32000)
```

Comment: ...because its parameter is in seconds, not milliseconds.

Comment: Removed your image, because it's not actually relevant to the python.